# How to dynamically replace values in pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to conditionally replace values in `pandas.DataFrame` using `mask` function, so imagine we have this dataframe:

```
     Col1           Col2
0    Qeq            10
1    Qeq            20
2    Qwa            30
```

What I want is to have an ability to replace all values where `Col1 == 'Qwa'` to f-string referencing OLD value dynamically. So my desired format is: "-{value}" and desired output is:

```
     Col1           Col2
0    Qeq            10
1    Qeq            20
2    Qwa            -30
```

Is it possible using `.mask` function?
I've tried following:

```py
# This works but new value in this case is hardcoded
df['Col2'].mask(df['Col1'] == 'Qwa', other='-' + df['Col2'])
# This does not work as it evaluates whole series in a f-string
df['Col2'].mask(df['Col1'] == 'Qwa', other=f'-{df["Col2"]}')
```

Comment: why not try to filter out the column, then use map()/apply() to effect the change you want?

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamically`? If you mean Excel style where you change `Col1`, `Col2` automatically changes, then no, it's not supported.

Comment: @Ade_1 Is it possible to reference old value in f-string-like and pass it as an argument?

Comment: @QuangHoang By "dynamically" i mean an ability to supply any f-string-like format to be replaced in dataframe/series. `NEW-VALUE(OLDVALUE:{value})` or any string like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `apply` the format function:

```
df['Col2'].mask(df['Col1'] == 'Qwa', other=df['Col2'].apply('-{}'.format))
```

Output:

```
0     10
1     20
2    -30
Name: Col2, dtype: object
```

Or

```
df['Col2'].mask(df['Col1'] == 'Qwa', other=df['Col2'].apply('*{}'.format))
```

Output:

```
0     10
1     20
2    *30
Name: Col2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this `df`:

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]: 
  Col1  Col2
0  Qeq    10
1  Qeq    20
2  Qwa    30
3  Qwa    40
```

You can something like, using `df.loc`:

```
In [66]: df.loc[df.Col1.eq('Qwa'), 'Col2'] = df.loc[df.Col1.eq('Qwa'), 'Col2'].mul(-1)

In [67]: df
Out[67]: 
  Col1  Col2
0  Qeq    10
1  Qeq    20
2  Qwa   -30
3  Qwa   -40
```

Comment: That's nice! Although, I need to work with strings and replace them via pattern using old values